# Python Code to Replace First Letter of String: String Index Error

Tags: python, string, character

Currently, I am working on parsing resumes to remove "-" only when it is used at the beginning of each line. I've tried identifying the first character of each string after the text has been split.  Below is my code:

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if line[0] == "-":
        line[0] = line.replace('-', ' ')
```

line is a string.  This is my way of thinking but every time I run this, I get the error `IndexError: string index out of range`.  I'm unsure of why because since it is a string, the first element should be recognized. Thank you!

Comment: if a line is empty `line[0]` is invalid. First test: `if line and line[0] == "-":`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're getting is because some lines are empty.

Then your replacement is wrong:

- first because it will assign the first "character" of the line but you cannot change a string because it's immutable
- second because the replacement value is the whole string minus some dashes
- third because `line` is lost at the next iteration. The original list of lines too, by the way.

If you want to remove the first character of a string, no need for `replace`, just slice the string (and don't risk to remove other similar characters).

A working solution would be to test with `startswith` and rebuild a new list of strings. Then join back

```
text = """hello
-yes--
who are you"""

new_text = []

for line in text.splitlines():
    if line.startswith("-"):
        line = line[1:]
    new_text.append(line)

print("\n".join(new_text))
```

result:

```
hello
yes--
who are you
```

with more experience, you can pack this code into a list comprehension:

```
new_text = "\n".join([line[1:] if line.startswith("-") else line for line in text.splitlines()])
```

finally, regular expression module is also a nice alternative:

```
import re
print(re.sub("^-","",text,flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

this removes the dash on all lines starting with dash. Multiline flag tells regex engine to consider `^` as the start of the line, not the start of the buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying! This makes so much sense after searching over and over again for why!

Answer (score 0):

this could be due to empty lines. You could just check the length before taking the index.

```
new_text = []
text="-testing\nabc\n\n\nxyz"
for line in text.split("\n"):
    if line and line[0] == '-':
        line = line[1:]
    new_text.append(line)

print("\n".join(new_text))
```

Comment: `if len(line) > 0` can be golfed to `if line`